# My matplotlib animation is slow, how to optimize it?

Tags: python, matplotlib, tkinter

I am doing an EEG in python using the matplotlib library,
I generate random informations and I display them in a Tkinter window,
I want to update the animation 10 times per seconds,
So 10 updates should last 1 second, right ?
But instead the animation lasts between 1.1 and 1.3 seconds ...
I guess this is an optimization issue ?

I will be very grateful if you could help me !

How my EEG looks like :

[my matplotlib's EEG at 17 seconds](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lr5UC.png)

[my matplotlib's EEG at 29 seconds](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LoRgr.png)

Here's my code (main.py):

```
import tkinter as tk
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('TkAgg')
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg 
from Sources.Model.grapheEEG5 import grapheEEG5
from matplotlib.animation import FuncAnimation

HAUTEUR = 768
LARGEUR = 1366
root = tk.Tk()
root.title("Interface logicielle d'acquisition")
fenetre = tk.Canvas(root, height=HAUTEUR, width=LARGEUR)
fenetre.pack()

fig = plt.Figure(figsize = (10, 6), dpi = 100)  

cadreMilieu = tk.Frame(fenetre, bg='white')
cadreMilieu.place(relx=0.1, rely=0.1, relwidth=0.8, relheight=0.8)

canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(fig, master = cadreMilieu).get_tk_widget().pack()
grapheDeroulant = grapheEEG5(8, fig, None, "EEG", "temps (en secondes)", "capteurs")

aniPoints = FuncAnimation(fig, grapheDeroulant.animation, cache_frame_data = False, 
                     save_count = 0, frames=None, blit=False, interval=100, repeat=False)

root.mainloop()
```

And my class (grapheEEG5.py):

```
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('TkAgg')
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import random as random
import time

class grapheEEG5:
    
    #variables
    axe = None
    figure = None
    toolbar = None
    tailleDonnees = None
    nbEEG = None
    compteur = 0
    
    #parametres
    echelle = 1.0/10
    periodeTrame = 0.1
    boucle = 0
    dureeSecondesFigure = 20
    
    #courbes
    ligneCurseur = None
    ordonnees = None
    ordonneesFantome = None 
    
    #coords curseur
    cursorY = None
    
    #coords vrais points
    xVraiPoints = []
    yVraiPoints = []
    
    def __init__(self, nbEEG, figure, toolbar, titre, nomx, nomy, grid = None):
        self.nbEEG = nbEEG
        self.cursorY = [0, -self.nbEEG-1]
        self.figure = figure
        self.tailleDonnees = int(self.dureeSecondesFigure / self.periodeTrame)
        print(self.tailleDonnees, "donnée(s)")
        self.axe = self.figure.add_subplot(111)
        self.axe.grid(ls="--", lw=0.5)
        self.axe.set_title(titre)
        self.axe.set_xlabel(nomx)
        self.axe.set_ylabel(nomy)
        self.axe.set_xlim(0, self.dureeSecondesFigure)
        self.axe.xaxis.set_major_locator(plt.MaxNLocator(self.dureeSecondesFigure))
        self.axe.set_ylim(-self.nbEEG-1,0)
        self.axe.get_yaxis().set_visible(False)
        
        for i in range(self.nbEEG):
            self.xVraiPoints.append([None]*self.tailleDonnees)
            self.yVraiPoints.append([None]*self.tailleDonnees)
        
        self.ordonnees = []
        self.ordonneesFantome = []
        for i in range(self.nbEEG):
            self.ordonnees.append(self.axe.plot([], [], lw=0.75, color="black", label="nouvelles valeurs")[0])
            self.ordonneesFantome.append(self.axe.plot([], [], lw=0.75, color="grey", label="anciennes valeurs")[0])
        self.ligneCurseur, = self.axe.plot([], [], color="red", label="curseur")
        
        if toolbar != None:
            self.toolbar = toolbar
            self.toolbar.update()
        
        for i in range(nbEEG):
            self.axe.text(-30*self.periodeTrame, -i-1, "capteur " + str(i+1))
            
        self.figure.canvas.draw()
            
    def animation(self, i):

        temps = self.compteur*self.periodeTrame
        
        for _ in range(self.nbEEG):
            self.xVraiPoints[_][self.compteur] = temps
            indexEeg = -_-1
            y = indexEeg + (random.randint(-3,3) * self.echelle)
            self.yVraiPoints[_][self.compteur] = y
            self.ordonnees[_].set_data(self.xVraiPoints[_], self.yVraiPoints[_])
        
        cursorX = [temps, temps]
        self.ligneCurseur.set_data(cursorX, self.cursorY)
        
        self.compteur += 1
        if self.compteur >= self.tailleDonnees:
            self.compteur = 0
 
        return self.ordonnees
```

Comment: I used a stop-watch in my system and I see that the animation is proceeding correctly. The time displayed in the chart correspond to the time in the stop-watch... Maybe you are using a very-very low-power pc?

Comment: Hi, thank you for answering, indeed I am using a low power pc. 20 seconds lasts 23 seconds on my graph. So I'm going to try on my desktop PC!

Comment: I tested it on a powerful computer and the issue is still there.

Comment: Not related to your problem but you might want to write the whole code in English, because otherwise you get a mix of French (from you) and English (from the various libs) and it becomes a bit disturbing.

Answer (score 0):

I printed the time when i call my animations referenced in funcAnimation and it seems that it is never the exact time, for example if i put interval = 0.5
then my script will call it after 0.46 sec or 0.56, and this is this approximation that was creating delay. Now i am using a manual animation and i am calling it with a method that does not drift and it works perfectly.

Comment: Could you please add the new code to this answer?